# Cache breaking URL not working in Chrome

Tags: javascript, image, google-chrome

I'm writing a routine that can rotate a picture after upload. The rotation is done on the server, and the image url does not change during this process.

The server routine works on response to an AJAX call, and on response, I'm doing the following:

```
var url = $img.attr("src");
url = url.replace(/\d+$/, (new Date()).getTime());
var $nimg = $('<img alt="avatar"/>');
$nimg.insertAfter($img);
$nimg.attr('src', url);
$nimg[0].src = url;
```

My image URL is loaded with ?q=25336532143 or whatever, so the variant images each get a different url.

My problem is that this process is not working in Chrome (maybe other browsers too, haven't checked). I'm getting additional images alongside my source image, each with differing values for q=, but they are each in the same orientation.

I had thought that adding a random or time based parameter broke the cache and forced download (plenty of StackOverlow messages suggest that this is the case), but this is not the case. I can actually see each variant url in the Network pane, but it never turns into a request in fiddler.

What's wrong? Cheers.

Mark

Comment: Not certain what issue is?

Comment: I have an image loaded in the browser + if I change it at the server, I want to change it's appearance in the browser without reloading the page. Adding a timestamp in the query parameters (apparently guaranteed to work) does not cause the image to reload - what's wrong?

Comment: _"Adding a timestamp in the query parameters (apparently guaranteed to work) does not cause the image to reload"_ Are you sure of this? Have you checked `Network` panel at `Inspector`? What do you mean by "change it at the server"?

Comment: I'm quite sure - because I've chosen to load the new URL into a separate image, I can see two identical images side by side, which should not be the case because Element Inspector shows two URLs.  The network panel does show a new URL, but Fiddler does not show an actual request. Change it at server means 'rotate by 90degrees'.

Comment: what if your server-code doesnt work as expected? have you confirmed the output somehow? Network Tab in chrome dev tools should show whether you are getting a cached response or not.

Comment: At server, image is rotated by 90 degrees, then filename of image file is set to same as previous image? What indication did you receive at client side from server that new file where image has been successfully rotated and previous file has been overwritten? Is cache enabled at browser? Can you reproduce the issue at jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net ? Have you tried using `css` `transform` to rotate original image ninety degrees, instead of performing a network request to achieve same effect?

Comment: Output is good, a 90deg rotated image. I can't rotate in CSS, because it's performing rotation on images that will be henceforth used as product images in a nopCommerce website. Remembering orientation and styling at each use point would be clever, but not what I'm trying to do.

Comment: I have managed to get a working system by returning a data Url via JSon and assigning that. This is obviously very inefficient!

Comment: Try to open the problematic image itself directly in a separate tab. Does it look as expected?